# Radio Button add url parameter

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

i am trying to add url parameter like ( www.example.com/product#green) this but i need multiple paramater like ( www.example.com/product#green#large ) after first parameter add size i wrote something but it doesn't work properly. But when user select size first should push parameter. When user click colour then size www.example.com/product#green#large

And i have another problem when i refresh the page the parameters stay there.I need to clear url parameters.I added jsFiddle link down below.

How can i do this with jquery.

```js
var currentUrl = window.location.href;

$("#colour-stage label").click(function() {
  var valColourInput = $('input[name=colour]:checked').val();
  document.location.href = currentUrl + '#' + valColourInput;
});

$("#size-stage label").click(function() {
  var valSizeInput = $('input[name=size]:checked').val();
  document.location.href = currentUrl + '#' + valSizeInput;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="get">

  <fieldset id="colour-stage">
    <legend>
      Colours:
    </legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Red">
      <span>Red</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Blue">
      <span>Blue</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Yellow">
      <span>Yellow</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Green">
      <span>Green</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="size-stage">
    <legend>
      Size:
    </legend>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small">
      <span>Small</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium">
      <span>Medium</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="size" value="large">
      <span>Large</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tolga748/06ekvf72/

Comment: Just FYI your fiddle is missing a reference to jQuery, and even when added you get an error: `val is not defined`. What is `val`?

Comment: as @RoryMcCrossan says, change `val` to either `valColourInput` or `valSizeInput` and include jquery then i think it will work

Comment: ı have changed it . It doesn't work properly again

Comment: this is new jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tolga748/06ekvf72/2/

Comment: hey,, take a look at this js plugin, you can manipulate hash very easy: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#fragment-abuse